# Java Keystore : missing decryptionKey and signingKey aliases

Tags: java, security, ssl, pfx, pkcs#12

I would need help about this exception that I don't understand... 
and I don't even find anything on google about that.

*java.security.KeyStoreException] : [The supplied keystore is not configured correctly, it must contain the '**decryptionKey**' alias and the '**signingKey**' alias at com.entrust.toolkit.x509.jsse.d.&lt

What are these aliases ? Do you have idea of the reason why they are missing?

This is the line of code throwing the exception

```
CLIENT_KEYSTORE_PATH = full path of the "client certificate" pfx file.
CLIENT_KEYSTORE_PASS = password of the pfx file

KeyStore cks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        cks.load(new FileInputStream(CLIENT_KEYSTORE_PATH), CLIENT_KEYSTORE_PASS.toCharArray());
        SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom().loadKeyMaterial(cks, CLIENT_KEYSTORE_PASS.toCharArray()).build();
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the keytool command that comes bundeld with Java binaries.

You can find how to use it googling on line.

Don't miss the key store type option to specify PKCS12

[Here there is a link to one place for example.](https://support.wandisco.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/374/0/using-java-keytool-to-manage-keystores)

Answer (score 0):

> **Error:** "The keystore does not contain a private key associated with this alias"

**Problem**
When importing a Code Signing Certificate for Sun Java or Symantec SSL Certificate into a keystore, you receive the following error:

Error: "The keystore does not contain a private key associated with this alias"

Cause
This error occurs when one of the following conditions are true:

- The certificate is being imported into the incorrect keystore.
- The certificate is being imported into the incorrect alias.

### Solution:

To resolve this problem:

- Locate the correct Keystore.  The keystore must be the same keystore
  that was used to originally generate the Certificate Signing Request
  (CSR).  If a new keystore was generated with the same name and alias,
  the hash will be different. Therefore, the certificate will still not
  match the private key in the keystore.
- Locate the correct alias.  To verify the alias, run the following
  command:

  `keytool -list -v -keystore [keystore name]`

The correct alias will state Entry type: keyEntry

Once you have located the correct keystore and alias, run the following command to import the certificate:

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore [keystore_filename] -alias [alias_name] -file [cert_file]
```

### Resource Link:

https://knowledge.symantec.com/support/code-signing-support/index?page=content&id=SO6863&pmv=print&actp=PRINT&viewlocale=en_US